# How to redirect to another HTML page by button click in a single page app using angular?

Tags: java, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am working on a single page application that contains sign in and registration and some other functionalities.I have page `index.html` that includes `signin.html` and `register.html` ,and the submit in the sign in should direct the user to `welcome.html`.
I understand how to use `ng-include` to put many html pages into one page but how can I use it in this situation ?

try `include.html`

```
<body  ng-app="myApp">
  <div >
     <div ng-include = "'tryinclude1.html'"></div>
  </div>
```

tryinclude1.html

```
<body>
<label>you are in tryinclude1 press ok to go to another page</label>
<button ng-include="'tryinclude1.html'">ok</button>
</body>
```

tryinclude2.html:

```
<body>
<label>you are in tryinclude2 press ok to go to another page</label>
<button ng-include="'tryinclude1.html'">ok</button>
</body>
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: post what you have tried yet.

Comment: If you are using ui-router, then use $state.go('stateName') and in the case, if   you are using ng Router, use $location.path('/newValue')

Comment: I posted @Stark Buttowski

Comment: check the `routing` concept in angular

Comment: @Stark Buttowski thank you so much,I understand better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is to use ng-hide and ng-show ,with no need for routing.
more detail here
https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-view and ng-route to manage your single page application.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView